# Creating a JVM from C

Tags: java, linker, java-native-interface

How does one start a Java VM from C? Writing the C code seems to be straigtforward -- I've been following the code that appears on p. 84 of Liang's "The Java Native Interface". It's the linking process that has me stymied. Liang's book is 10+ years out of date in that regard and I can't find anything on the net which addresses this goal (and which works).

To be clear, what I want to do is launch a standard windows program (written in C), which then launches the JVM and calls a main() in a Java class (which I have written). This program should not rely the presence of jvm.dll or jvm.lib -- the user shouldn't have to install Java to run the program. Maybe this isn't possible without an unreasonable amount of effort.

The development environment is MinGW under windows. I'm able to link in such a way that the program works when the .dll is in a separate file, but not in a way so that there's only a single executable without any .dlls or .libs.

---

In hindsight, I can see now that this was a dumb question, or at least one that hadn't been thought through. The moral of the story is that the "JVM" is not a single executable, or even an executable plus some JAR files; the JVM relies on a slew of independently stored files with various mutual dependencies. Unraveling all of these relationships so that they could be brought into a single file (or even two files) would be a massive undertaking. Thanks for the knock in the head.

Comment: What about the Java's standard library JARs? Are you happy to redistribute them or are you wanting to bundle them into the executable too?

Comment: That's simple. Just install a compiler, deliver the JDK source code, compile the source code and then run the JVM! No honestly, how do you imagine running a non existent program should work? You obviously need the JVM so that you can run it. And how you do that - look at the gamma launcher in the source.

Comment: I think the criticism you got here is totally unfair - I don't think this is a dumb question even a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

So, to be clear - you want to launch a JVM without the requirement of a JVM being present? How do you propose to accomplish that? Unless you're contemplating writing your own JVM implementation (which I'd say falls under the category "unreasonable amount of effort"), having a JVM installed is a reasonable requirement. Assuming that, you can just spawn a java process and include the appropriate command-line parameters (classpath, class to run etc).

Comment: Ideally, the end result would be two files: an executable, which includes the JVM proper, and a JAR file that includes any of the necessary class definitions shipped with Java, together with any additional classes written for the particular problem.

Comment: Yes, if doing this involves an entire redesign of the entire framework under which Java normally launches and executes, then it is an "unreasonable amount of effort."

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer:  I don't think that having a Java runtime installed is unreasonable for users.  That said, I do understand your motivations for a low-friction install for users.

Using the Sun JRE is probably not going to be fruitful here.  In theory, you could grab the Sun JRE, modify it to build as a static library instead of a DLL and figure out a way to cram all the resources that get bundled with it (fonts, images, cursors, SSL certificates, localized message files, etc.) into a single resource and then modify the runtime to load from there.  But this is almost certainly an "unreasonable amount of effort."

You might want to look at GCJ instead:  its architecture is different than the Sun JRE which lends itself more to being embedded in another application, or it can compile your Java to native machine code.

(Also, do check the licensing to ensure that you can properly redistribute this no matter which route you take.)